# cell array of strings to matlab structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell

I need to create a matlab structure as such `ds=struct('name',{{'my_name_is'},{'matlab_thining_hair'}})` which stores as a 1x2 struct array with fields: name. A call to ds.name generates the output:

> > ds.name
> >
> > ans = 
> >     'my_name_is'
> >
> > ans =
> >     'matlab_thining_hair'

Please note the single quotes in the output. They are important. That said, I need to create the above mentioned structure using the following variable:
X = [1x46 char] [1x47 char] i.e., 1x2 cell, which I believe is actually a cell array of strings. Among other things, I've tried the following:

`Y = cell2struct(X, 'name', 1)'`

which results in a 1x2 structure array with fields name, however a call to Y generates the output:

> > Y.name
> >
> > ans = my_name_is
> >
> > ans = matlab_thining_hair

Note that the single quotes in the output are missing, and albeit both Y and ds are 1x2 struct arrays with fields name, the field values are not formatted the same and the structures also vary in their bytes size. How to format the field values as character arrays?

Answer (score 1):

In your first case you have created a struct with two fields whose values are cell arrays. The  cell arrays are displayed with quotes.

In your second case your struct fields have char arrays which is what you want. Char arrays display without quotes.

You can verify this by typing in your command prompt {'abc'} and then 'abc'.

In your first case you can create non-cell array field values by passing the strings outside cell parenthesis.

ds=struct('name',{'my_name_is','matlab_thining_hair'})

Comment: Thank you Navan. But what I actually need is a struct with fields with cell arrays, where essentially each cell array consists of a unique char array. Your recommendation works for a struct with single cell array field value, but that is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Stick your char strings in another layer of cells before calling cell2struct. Instead of:

```
X = { 'foo', 'bar' }
```

Try:

```
X = { {'foo'}, {'bar'} }
```

That is, a 1-by-2 cell whose cell contents are themselves cells, not chars. Then `cell2struct(X, 'name', 1)` should give you a struct array with fields of cell arrays.

If your existing X is a cellstr, I think you can just call `num2cell` on it to push each cell down into another layer of cell indirection.